# CakePHP Internationalization locale codes

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization, multilingual

I have some troubles with locale codes in CakePHP 1.3 (but also applicable for 2.0)

I am using the 3 letter codes for the languages but some codes are not available. For example I would like to setup `aus` for Australia. As the documentation says

> The three-character locale codes conform to the ISO 639-2 standard, although if you       create regional locales (en_US, en_GB, etc.) cake will use them if appropriate.

And `aus` exists in `ISO 639-2` but does not work with CakePHP. It saves the i18n record but when displaying the content it takes the english version. Just the same happens when putting code that is not available in the ISO standard. Also I have tried with the location based code `en_AU` and the result is the same.

Am I able to make any code to work, no matter if it is according the ISO standard. This is because in the site administrator has access to the languages in the site and I would like to allow him to use any combination of letters to use as a code for the language.

Also how to get setup code for Australia

Comment: How do you set the language? Using `Configure::write('Config.language', 'en-au')`? (note the dash / https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3/lib/Cake/I18n/L10n.php ). The folder then would be "en_au"

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell cake what language you are using for your translation.
You can use general 3-letter codes (like eng) or more location specific codes (like en-US).

In your case:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'en-au')
```

note the dash ( https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3/lib/Cake/I18n/L10n.php ).

The folder then would be "en_au" in `/APP/Locale/`